# can i know pls the INPUT variable why it's giving me error always, thank you so much

Tags: android, user-input, gettext

can i know pls why the `input` variable why it's giving me error always, thank you so much.

This is my code below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

      public TextView textView;
       public EditText editText;
      public Button btn;
      public int input;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView=findViewById(R.id.textView);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);

      ` input= Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());`


        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                textView.setText(input );

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are trying to parse the input string from editText in onCreate() as soon as the view is created. This will try to parse the default text associated with the editText. I think what you want is to parse the input at the time of clicking button. In that case move the input parsing code inside onClick(). Also it is better to catch NumberFormatException when calling parseInt() if you cannot guarantee that the text entered in the EditText is always an integer.

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        android.util.Log.i("MyActivity", "onClick: edit text = " + editText.getText());
        input= Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
        textView.setText(input );
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast response, i did it and moved the input line after the on click view ,but also it gives me error ,sorry for bothering but i did it in the morning and now its not working don't know what is the mistake.

Comment: Can you paste the error message that you are getting? I assumed it was NumberFormatException when trying to parse the text from EditText. Make sure that the text entered in EditText is always an integer. I have edited the answer to include a Log statement which can print the text in EditText at the time of clicking the button. Another way is to use the debugger option in your Android studio to check the values.

Answer (score 0):

The error is happening as the `String` cant be cast to an `integer`. This could be because your editText is empty or that you have characters that are not integers in there (E.g. Letters). Therefor you should use `try` and `catch` to catch the error.